# Select Max Count of consecutive rows with same value mariaDB mysql

Tags: mariadb

[image: example table]

I got a table like this, and i want to get the largest consecutive count of rows where win=1 for each puuid and ordered by game_creation DESC. I tried many solution of the web but can't get any of them to work, maybe somebody here can help me.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)